# wxPython inactive state?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

Right now I'm working on a program using wxPython, and I want to make a GUI in which under certain conditions, the widgets become inactive and the user can't interact with them. I'm pretty sure I have seen this in programs before, but I can't come up with a specific example. Is there a way to do this in wxPython? I have no idea what the technical name for this is, so even giving me that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "the objects", what do you mean? If you mean a wx Frame, then you can call `Frame.Freeze()` to disable the frame, and `Frame.Thaw()` to unfreeze it. If you want to create a new dialog that must be interacted with and make all background windows unuseable, you can call `Dialog.ShowModal()`. Finally, many widgets have a `Widget.Enable()` function, to which you can pass `True` or `False` depending on if you want to enable it or not.

Comment: Sorry, I meant individual widgets, but that answered my question. Thanks!